# How to change data in cell in dynamic UITableView xcode project?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a Dynamic Prototypes Table view that has different cells, I'm adding the cells to the table view and I want to change their content. All the tutorials I find is for a tableview with only one type of cell, but I have 8 different types. How would I change their content (ie, textfields etc) and how would I get actions from them back to the main tableview controller to do some business logic? (ie button pressed etc)

What I did is:

1. I created a costume class for each cell type and connected them under customClass, class field.

   [image]
2. I attached the textfields etc, actions and references to these classes.
3. this is my cellAtRow function I assume I would change it in this function somehow?
   or reference the classes from here?

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


       print ("indexPath: ", indexPath)
       print ("indexPath: ", indexPath[0])
       print ("-------")

       if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "header") {
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell", for: indexPath)

           return cell

       } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "description") {
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerInfoCell", for: indexPath)

           return cell

       } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "diagnoses") {
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "diagnosisCell", for: indexPath)

           return cell

       } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "perscription") {
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "perscriptionCell", for: indexPath)

           return cell

       } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "notes") {
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "notesCell", for: indexPath)

           return cell

       } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "addFaxHeadline") {

           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addFaxCell", for: indexPath)

           return cell

       } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "addFax") {

           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "emailNameCell", for: indexPath)

           return cell


       } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "addEmailHeadline") {

           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addEmailCell", for: indexPath)

           return cell


       } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "addEmails") {

           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "emailNameCell", for: indexPath)

           return cell


       } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "givePermissionHeadline") {

           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "permissionCell", for: indexPath)

           return cell

       } else if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "select answer") {

           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "selectAnswerCell", for: indexPath)

           return cell
       }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast your cells to the class they belong. On the second line of the code block you can see an example of this.

```
if (sectionsData[indexPath[0]] == "header") {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderTableViewCell

    cell.titleLbl.text = "Title"
    cell.delegate = self // To receive actions back

    return cell
}

. . . // More of the same

// default return
```

To send calls back to your main view controller you can add protocols to your cells like so:

```
protocol HeadTableViewCellProcol{
    func bttnPressed()
}

class HeadTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

    var delegate: HeadTableViewCellProcol?

    @IBAction func bttnPressedInCell(){
        delegate?.bttnPressed()
    }
}
```

The this of this protocols like the protocols you had to implement for your UITableView. You will also have to implement these protocols in your main VC.

Comment: everything is good but the protocols dont get read, in the tableview controller and in the view controller itself

Comment: @ChiefMadog What do you mean? Do you have one tableviewcontroller? Are you asking how to implement your protocol to actually receive call backs?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderTableViewCell
```

to call `cell.yourTextField.text` for example

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `UITableViewCell` into your dynamic cell class. You can try the following:

```
guard let cell = tableView. dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "perscription", for: indexPath) as? PerscriptionTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

cell.setupCell() //You have access to cell's public funcs and vars now
return cell
```

Using optional unwrapping, you can be sure that your app is likely to be safe from type casting crashes.

Comment: Please don't conditionally downcast  cells. **Force unwrap** them. It's safe. The code must not crash unless you made a **design** mistake

Comment: @vadian It is OK that your app has some functionality problems, or doesn't work as intended, but it is not accepted that your app crashes. The reasean is not important, you have to always prevent potential crash points.

Comment: Once again, the code cannot crash if everything is hooked up correctly at **design time**. There is no *potential crash point*

Comment: Yes, it can. Consider your friend has a nib file containing a custom `UITableViweCell` and has registered it to the `tableview` with a different cell identifier. Or you can imagine your teammate changed the type cell to another custom `UITableViewCell`. You can't say you don't make mistakes. In general, you have to try avoiding force unwrapping in your code. (https://blog.timac.org/2017/0628-swift-banning-force-unwrapping-optionals/)

Comment: @vadian Very good point. Although if you are loading a table like the one above with a lot of different cells conditionally down casting can be good to avoid crashes on edge case cells. Especially if there isn't full UI testing, you might break a link ant not notice for some time.

Comment: No offense but runtime checks like conditional downcasts as an alibi for the carelessness not to test the UI is ridiculous. Do your homework. Yes, the code does not crash but the table view doesn’t work either and most likely you will get compile errors about missing outlets anyway. There are only a few cases where force unwrapping is useful. This is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

As the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell) says, the return type of the **dequeueReusableCell** is a **UITableViewCell**.

`Apple Documentation
Return Value: A UITableViewCell object with the associated identifier or nil if no such object exists in the reusable-cell queue.`

Your custom cells classes should inherit from UITableViewCell and to be able to use an instance of your custom cell you need to cast the returning UITableViewCell of the dequeReusableCell into your desire custom cell type.

`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCellIdentifierCell", for: indexPath) as! YourCutsomTableViewCell`

For customizing, every cell is responsible for his own configuration. You should have a function (you can use protocols or inherit from a superclass) and inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath, after casting it, call the setup function.

`customCell.setup() //you can add some parameters if its needed`